# React map function stop working on state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I'm trying to make an update on an Object that is in the state using React Hooks, but when I try to update the Objet the function `.map` stop working.

First I have this `handleCheckedFilterChange` function and it change the state Object but the component was not re-render:

```
const handleCheckedFilterChange = (name) => {
    let prevFilters = filters;
    for (let filter in prevFilters) {
      if (prevFilters[filter].name === name) {
        prevFilters[filter].checked = !prevFilters[filter].checked;
        prevFilters[filter].filters.map((value) => {
          value.disabled = !value.disabled;
        });
        setFilters(prevFilters);
        break;
      }
    }
};
```

So then I change it to this one to make the component render again:

```
const handleCheckedFilterChange = (name) => {
    let prevFilters = { ...filters };
    for (let filter in prevFilters) {
      if (prevFilters[filter].name === name) {
        prevFilters[filter].checked = !prevFilters[filter].checked;
        prevFilters[filter].filters.map((value) => {
          value.disabled = !value.disabled;
        });
        setFilters(prevFilters);
        break;
      }
    }
};
```

But this second one generates me an error:

> TypeError: filters.map is not a function

The error is when I call the following:

```
const renderCards = filters.map((filter) => (
    <div className="card text-center">
      ...
    </div>
));
```

Comment: In the first moment when I run the project, the initial object renders fine.

Comment: You should use `let prevFilters = [ ...filters ]`

Comment: Re-rendering `filters` may mean it isn't an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first option you are trying to modify the state directly which is not allowed in React's `useState` and that's why it is not rendering your expected change.

The problem with the second option is your are trying to use `{}` instead of `[]`. Try as:

```
let prevFilters = [ ...filters ];
```

The reason behind is [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a function on arrays and not on objects.